# jQuery multiple selectbox issue

Tags: jquery

I have fancy looking jQuery Multiple checkbox/selectbox list script.

Look [HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/FRBqW/2/) for demo.

This is domain availability lookup form.

Issue is I am getting value of  `<input type="text" name="domain" size="20"/>` in search

results for unchecked checkbox.

It should be NO RESULTS FOR UNCHECKED CHECKBOX.

Here is script :

```
(function(jQuery) {

    jQuery.fn.custSelectBox = function(options){
        
        //css names
        var classselectbox = "selectbox";
        var selectbox = "." + classselectbox;
        var selectboxoptions_wrap = ".selectboxoptions_wrap";
        var hideitem = "hideitem";
        var classselected = "selected";
        var classselectboxopen = "selectboxopen";
        var classselectboxfoot ="selectboxfoot";
        var selectboxfoot = "." +classselectboxfoot;
        var elmValue = ".elmValue";
        
        var defaults = {
                isscrolling:    true,               //scrolls long lists
                scrollminitems: 15,                 //items before scrolling
                scrollheight:   150,                //height of scrolling window
                preopenselect:  true,               //opens prechecked select boxes
                hoverstyle:     "hover",            //css hover style name
                openspeed:      "normal",           //selectbox open speed "slow","normal","fast" or numbers 1000
                alldisabled:    false,              //disables the selectbox
                selectwidth:    "auto",             //set width of selectbox
                wrappername:    ".select_wrap"
            };
        //override defaults
        var opts = jQuery.extend(defaults, options);

        return this.each(function() { 
        
        /** FUNCTIONS **/
        jQuery.fn.disable = function(thisElm){
            //loop through items
            for(var i=0;i<jQuery(thisElm).find("ul").find("li").length;i++)
            {
                if(jQuery(jQuery(thisElm).find("ul").find("li").get(i)).hasClass(classselected))
                {
                    jQuery(jQuery(thisElm).find("ul").find("li").get(i)).addClass("selected_disable");
                }
                jQuery(jQuery(thisElm).find("ul").find("li").get(i)).unbind();
                jQuery(jQuery(thisElm).find("ul").get(i)).find("input").attr("enabled","enabled");
            }               
        };
    
        //adds form elements to the selectbox
        jQuery.fn.addformelms = function(thisElm){
                var currElm = jQuery(thisElm);
                var boxtype = jQuery(thisElm).find(selectboxoptions_wrap+ " ul").attr("class");
                
                if(boxtype.indexOf("selectboxoptions_radio") >-1)
                {
                    var radioVal = jQuery(currElm).find("."+classselected+" span").text();
                    jQuery(currElm).find(selectboxoptions_wrap).append("<input type=\"text\" id=\""+jQuery(main_currElm).attr("id")+"\" name=\""+jQuery(main_currElm).attr("name")+"\" value=\""+radioVal+"\">");
                }
                else
                {
                    for(var i=0;i<jQuery(currElm).find(selectboxoptions_wrap + " li").length;i++)
                    {
                        var currInnerElm = jQuery(currElm).find(selectboxoptions_wrap + " li").get(i);
                        jQuery(currInnerElm).append("<input type=\"hidden\" id=\""+jQuery(main_currElm).attr("id") +"_"+ i+"\" name=\""+jQuery(main_currElm).attr("name") +"_"+ i+"\" value=\"\">");
                        
                        if(jQuery(currInnerElm).hasClass(classselected))
                        {
                            var checkVal = jQuery(currInnerElm).find("span").text();
                            jQuery(jQuery(currElm).find(selectboxoptions_wrap + " li").get(i)).find("input").val(checkVal);
                        }
                    }
                }
        };
        
        //opens selectboxs if they have pre selected options
        jQuery.fn.openSelectBoxsThatArePrePopulated = function(currElm)
        {
                var boxtype = jQuery(currElm).find(selectboxoptions_wrap+ " ul").attr("class");
                
                if(jQuery(selectbox).parent().find("." +boxtype).find("li").hasClass(classselected))
                {
                    jQuery(selectbox).addClass(classselectboxopen);
                    jQuery(selectbox).parent().find(selectboxoptions_wrap).slideDown("normal");
                    jQuery(selectbox).parent().find("." +boxtype).find("li").addClass(hideitem);
                }
        };
        
        jQuery.fn.scrolling = function (theElm, isOpen)
        {
            if(isOpen)
            {
                if(jQuery(theElm).parent().find(selectboxoptions_wrap+ " ul li").length >= opts.scrollminitems){
                    jQuery(theElm).parent().find(selectboxoptions_wrap+ " ul").css("height",opts.scrollheight).addClass("setScroll");
                }
            }
            else{
                jQuery(theElm).parent().find(selectboxoptions_wrap+ " ul").css("height","auto").removeClass("setScroll");
            }
        };
        /** FUNCTIONS **/
        
        //BUILD HTML TO CREATE CUSTOM SELECT BOX
        var main_currElm = jQuery(this);
        var wrapperElm = jQuery(main_currElm).parent();
        var name = "";
        var select_options = jQuery(main_currElm).find("option");
        var opts_str="";
        var isDisabled = jQuery(main_currElm).attr("disabled");
        var isMulti = jQuery(main_currElm).attr("multiple");
        var boxtype = "selectboxoptions_radio";
        var disabled = "";
        
        if(isMulti){boxtype = "selectboxoptions_check";}
        if(isDisabled){disabled="disabled";}
        //loop through options
        for(var i=0;i<select_options.length;i++)
        {
            var checked="";
            var currOption = jQuery(select_options).get(i);
                                  
                               if(i===0){
                name =jQuery(currOption).text();
            }
            else
            {               
                               if(jQuery(currOption).attr("selected")){checked ="selected";}

                opts_str = opts_str + "<li class=\""+checked +" "+disabled+"\"><span class=\"elmValue\">"+jQuery(currOption).val()+"</span>"+jQuery(currOption).text()+"</li>";
            }
        }
        
        jQuery(wrapperElm).empty().html("<div class=\"selectbox\"><ul><li>"+name+"</li></ul></div><div class=\"selectboxoptions_wrap\"><ul class=\""+boxtype+"\">"+opts_str+"</ul></div>");
        jQuery(wrapperElm).find(selectboxoptions_wrap +" ul").after("<div class=\""+classselectboxfoot+"\"><div></div></div>"); //add footer
        
        if("auto" != opts.selectwidth){
            jQuery(wrapperElm).find(selectbox + " ul").css({width:opts.selectwidth});
            jQuery(wrapperElm).find(selectboxoptions_wrap + " ul").attr("class",boxtype).css({width:(opts.selectwidth+57) + "px"});
            jQuery(wrapperElm).find(selectboxfoot + " div").css({width:opts.selectwidth + "px"});
        }else{
            jQuery(wrapperElm).find(selectboxoptions_wrap + " ul").attr("class",boxtype).css({width:(jQuery(wrapperElm).find(selectbox + " ul").width()+57) + "px"});
            jQuery(wrapperElm).find(selectboxfoot + " div").css({width:jQuery(wrapperElm).find(selectbox + " ul").width() + "px"});
        }

        if(isDisabled){jQuery.fn.disable(jQuery(wrapperElm).find(selectboxoptions_wrap));}
        
        var thisElement = jQuery(opts.wrappername);

        //bind item clicks
        jQuery(selectboxoptions_wrap+ " ul li").unbind().click( function() {
            
            if(jQuery(this).attr("class").indexOf("disabled") < 0)
            {
                var id;
                var boxtype = jQuery(this).parent().attr("class");
                
                if(boxtype.indexOf("selectboxoptions_radio") >-1)
                {
                    if(!jQuery(this).hasClass(classselected))
                    {
                        id = jQuery(this).find(elmValue).text();
                        jQuery(this).parent().find("." + classselected).removeClass(classselected);
                        jQuery(this).addClass(classselected);
                        jQuery(this).parent().parent().find("input").val(jQuery(this).find(elmValue).text());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        jQuery(this).parent().find("." + classselected).removeClass(classselected);
                        jQuery(this).parent().parent().find("input").val("");
                    }
                }
                else //checkbox
                {
                    if(jQuery(this).hasClass(classselected))
                    {
                        //turn off the checkbox
                        jQuery(this).removeClass(classselected);
                        //blank out the value                       
                                                jQuery(this).find("input").val("");
                                                id = jQuery(this).find(elmValue).text();  
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //gets the value of the element
                        id = jQuery(this).find(elmValue).text();    
                        jQuery(this).addClass(classselected);
                        jQuery(this).find("input").val(id);
                    }
                }
            }
        }).hover(function(){
            jQuery(this).addClass(opts.hoverstyle);
        },function(){
            jQuery(this).removeClass(opts.hoverstyle);
        });

        //bind sliding open
        jQuery(thisElement).find(selectbox).unbind().toggle(
            function() {
                if(opts.isscrolling){jQuery.fn.scrolling(jQuery(this),true);}
                //unhide li
                jQuery(this).parent().find(selectboxoptions_wrap+ " ul li").removeClass(hideitem);
                //makes the arrow go up or down
                jQuery(this).removeClass(classselectbox).addClass(classselectboxopen);
                //slides the options down
                jQuery(this).parent().find(selectboxoptions_wrap).slideDown(opts.openspeed);
            },
            function() {
                var boxtype = jQuery(this).parent().find(selectboxoptions_wrap+ " ul").attr("class");
                if(jQuery(this).parent().find(selectboxoptions_wrap+ " ul li").hasClass(classselected))
                {
                    jQuery(this).parent().find(selectboxoptions_wrap+ " ul li").addClass(hideitem);
                }   
                else
                {
                    //makes the arrows go up or down
                    jQuery(this).removeClass(classselectboxopen).addClass(classselectbox);
                    //slides the options up
                    jQuery(this).parent().find(selectboxoptions_wrap).slideUp("normal");
                }
                
                if(opts.isscrolling){jQuery.fn.scrolling(jQuery(this),false);}
            });
        
            
            jQuery.fn.addformelms(jQuery(wrapperElm));
            if(opts.preopenselect){ jQuery.fn.openSelectBoxsThatArePrePopulated(jQuery(wrapperElm));}
            if(opts.alldisabled){jQuery.fn.disable(jQuery(thisElement));}
        });
        
    };
    
})(jQuery);
```

What Is wrong ? why it is passing inputbox value for unchecked domain ?

Thanx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just tested this (Firefox 3.6.6).

As a test, I entered "google" as the domain and checked ".net" and ".us" in the special selectbox.

Firebug shows that the POST action, performed when I submitted the form, had the following variables:

```
domain  google
tlds[]_0    
tlds[]_1    .net
tlds[]_2    .us
```

I then submitted the form, with a domain of "google" and no extensions selected. FireBug then showed the following parameters being POSTed:

```
domain  google
tlds[]_0    
tlds[]_1    
tlds[]_2
```

The response which was seen in the browser, in each case, did show "*Issue is I am getting value of INPUTBOX in search results for unchecked checkbox. It should be NO RESULTS FOR UNCHECKED CHECKBOX.*"

If you are generating that message, it may help to just have a simple PHP page containing:

```
<h2>POST Variables</h2>
<pre><?php var_dump( $_POST ); ?></pre>
<h2>GET Variables</h2>
<pre><?php var_dump( $_GET ); ?></pre>
```

It may be that your form handler is not looking for the parameters in the correct fashion - this should show exactly what the form handler is getting.

Comment: I just did this myself, by creating a file containing the above suggested PHP code, and then changing the form handler to that file, hosted locally via XAMPP. The results I got for the above input (domain "google" and no checkboxes) was - $_POST['domain']='google', $_POST['tlds'][0]='', $_POST['tlds'][1]='', $_POST['tlds'][2]=''. The submissions are working correctly, check your handler's code.

Comment: Welcome. Just make sure that any changes you make to the handler will still be able to accept submissions from forms which have not been enhanced with the jQuery plugin. Have to remember to allow for graceful degradation, should, for instance, a visitor have javascript switched off.